# same-way tag questions and broadly negative elements

Tags: negation, tag-questions

Some books say there are two types of tag questions: the ordinary type and the same-way type. The ordinary type is used to make an assumption or guess and seek confirmation from the hearer. The form of the tag takes different polarity from the hosting clause, i.e., a negative clause requires a positive tag, and vice versa.

On the other hand, a same-way tag is used to question the truth of a statement, perhaps aggressively. The form of the tag takes the same polarity as the hosting clause,  i.e., a negative clause requires a negative tag, and a positive clause takes a positive tag.

ESL books also say expressions such as *seldom*, *hardly*, and *few* are negative elements. I'm wondering if the following sentences containing such elements should be considered instances of ordinary or same-way tags, and how they are interpreted:

**EDIT**: As *seldom* is not common in daily use, I think it might be more natural to replace it with **rarely**.

> a. He seldom/rarely comes here, doesn't he?

> b. He seldom/rarely comes here, does he?

> c. There were very few tourists on the beach, weren't there?

> d. There were very few tourists on the beach, were there?

> e. There were only a few tourists on the beach, weren't there?

> f. There were only a few tourists on the beach, were there?

Comment: In ordinary conversation "He doesn't often come here, does he?" and "There weren't many tourists on the beach, were there?" would be much more likely ways to put those questions. I would see (e) as seeking confirmation and (f) as challenging a statement.

Comment: Maybe it's the "seldom" that causes you to find the sentences a bit unnatural. What if "rarely" is used instead? What are your interpretations?

Comment: Looking at the first example, I'd say the negated tag in ***I rarely/seldom eat out, don't I?*** simply isn't idiomatic in the first place. @Kate's "seeking confirmation" and "challenging a statement" distinction applies quite naturally with ***I often eat out, [don't / do] I?***, but not with ***rarely***. And the *reason* for this is probably connected to the fact that as everyone would agree, ***I never eat out, do I?*** is fine, but ***I never eat out, don't I?*** is just nonsensical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How do you interpret b?

Comment: Your example (b) is the same as my ***I never eat out, do I?*** To all intents and purposes, ***never, seldom, rarely,*** etc. are all "syntactically equivalent negations" in such contexts, which is why they only really license the "confirmation of (fully or partially) negated statement" tag question ***do I?***. But it's worth noting that the somewhat ***less*** "negating" form *I **occasionally** eat out* allows both forms of tag, with the different meanings as set out by Kate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How do you find c and d? Which is used to seek confirmation rather than express anger or other emotions?

Comment: I think ***very few*** is like ***seldom, rarely*** - although they're all "weaker" than explicitly negating ***none, never***, that's how they should be treated in relation to tag questions. You do realise that "incorrect" use of tag questions can come across as insulting, **don't you**? / **do you?** If you're not 100% sure your intended sense will be understood, you should be very careful how you use them (bearing in mind tag questions are *never* actually necessary).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comments are exactly in line with what ESL books say. However, some people seem to think "little" or "few" play no role in question tag formation.  They think "There were very few tourists on the beach, weren’t there?" is a question tag on a par with "There were a few tourists on the beach, weren’t there?" in that both take negative tags and are intended to seek confirmation.  See https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/only-a-few-werent-there-tag-question.3809498/ , especially a post by a user named heypresto.

Comment: People who say things like *"There were very few tourists on the beach, weren’t there?"* aren't very fluent speakers of English. Most native speakers would avoid that in favour of, for example, *"There were **only a few** tourists on the beach, weren’t there?"* because even when qualified by ***only***, ***a** few* (with that all-important article) is still effectively a "positive polarity" item (there weren't ***none***), so it's okay to use the opposite (negating) tag question format for the "seeking confirmation" sense (OR ***...were there**?* for the "challenging, disbelieving" sense).